# Using "En Dash" in an input file to a batch file

Tags: command-line, encoding, character-encoding

Most tragically, I got several TFS team projects with an en dash in them.

If you are not familiar with en dash, open up MS Word and type in alt+8211.

You will see a larger looking dash.  (Like this if it renders for you: –).  If you open notepad you will see a ? and if you try it in most Unicode editors you will see ‼.

But I need it to be a dash.  Because I need to run a batch file against all my projects.  The paths to the projects now has this en dash in it.

I make a file that holds the names of the projects and I feed them to my batch file.

But when it runs it puts û in place of the –.

What can I do to keep my dash?

NOTE:
I have two batch files.  The First runs the second with params from a file.

My First one can be [seen here](https://gist.github.com/967578#file_update_reports_in_all_projects.bat).  The second can be [seen here](https://gist.github.com/967583#file_update_report_in_project.bat).  An example of the input file can be [seen here](https://gist.github.com/967588#file_project_list.txt).

Comment: An en dash is correctly inserted into any Windows application with ALT+0150. This works in notepad and any other program, as long as the current font supports it. I use them all the time.

Comment: @Jeffery - I would be interested in knowing a font that will allow the en dash to be inserted into notepad.

Comment: The input file that you posted is in UTF-8. Is that the encoding that the file is in or did it get converted when it was posted?

Comment: @Jeffery - That was converted when it was posted.  I have tried the input file with many different encodings (including 1252).  None of them work (I get ?, ‼, and some other values, but never the en dash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The en dash character is Unicode code point U+2013. In Windows code page 1252 it is character number 150. The û charcter is character number 150 in code page 437. So it looks like one process is writing a file in code page 1252, while another is reading it using code page 437.

Ideally, all code pages other than Unicode should be thrown out along with World Wars, small pox, and other relics of the 20th century. Unfortunately, the Windows console makes this rather difficult.

Since code page 437 is the default console code page for most Windows installations, I suspect that it is this default setting that is causing these problems. (File names are stored by the OS in Unicode, so that part, at least, is correct.) Since code page 437 does not include the en dash character, any system using that code page will have to resort to a fallback mechanism to render the file names, such as a question mark.

By changing the console code page to something that does support the en dash character, such as 1252, this problem may be corrected.

You can change this code page with the following command.

```
chcp 1252
```

This command should probably be placed at the beginning of your batch file.

This is a terrible hack that will be necessary until you can convert your system to something modern that supports Unicode from top to bottom.

You may also want to try it in Powershell, since PS does support Unicode.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  However, changing the char set (or using powershell) did not work (I still get û).  I am using the "for" command in my batch file to load from the file.  Could that be using a default charset to load from?  (My for command goes like this: `for /F  "delims=," %%a in (ProjectList.txt) do UpdateReportInProject.bat "http://TFS2010Prod/ReportServer" "%%a"`

Comment: I updated my question with links to my batch files and the sample input in case you wanted to look at it.

Comment: Does the `chcp 1252` command "stick"?  Meaning if I call it in a command prompt should it affect the whole window?  I ask because I ran `chcp 1252` and it said that the Active code page was 1252.  I then tried to paste in the en dash and it pasted in as a û.

Comment: @Vaccano - Yes, it should affect the whole window until it is closed or something else changes the code page.

Comment: @Vaccano - I was able to reproduce that problem. Interesting. Further research shows that the CHCP command does not support code page 1252, even though it doesn't return an error. The solution will have to be something else.

Comment: @Vaccano - Futher tests show that the console is using CP-1252, but it is displaying character 150 as though it were using CP-437. This is a font problem. Changing the font from "Rastor Fonts" to "Lucida Console" fixes the display problem.

Comment: @Vaccano - Try using code page 65001. That is UTF-8. Maybe it will give you better results. But definitely change the font on your console window first.

Comment: Wow!  Changing the font fixed it.  That is just crazy.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I saw no fix here, and it took me some searching before I tried my own fix.

In Notepad, I changed my font from 'Lucinda Console' to 'TERMINAL', and the dashes (–) changed to The  (û) symbol.  I just manually used the - on my keyboard using that font, saved my BAT script, and it executed fine.