# reconstructing path from outlined directory structure

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

I have a csv file in the form:

> Address,L0,L1,L2,L3,L4
>
> 01,Species,,,,
>
> 01.01,,Mammals,,,
>
> 01.01.01,,,Threatened,,
>
> ...

I want to use it to create a matching directory structure. I'm new to scripting and PowerShell, and in this case I'm not sure if I'm on totally the wrong track. Should I use a separate array to store each level's Name/Address pairs and then use those arrays like a lookup table to build the path? If so, I guess I'm stuck on how to set up if-thens based on a row's Address. This is as far as I've got so suggestions on general strategy or links to similar kinds of problem would be really welcome:

```
$folders = Import-Csv "E:\path\to\file.csv"

$folders | foreach {
$row = new-object PSObject -Property @{
    Address = $_.Address;
    Level = ([regex]::Matches($_.Address, "\." )).count;
    L0 = $_.L0
    L1 = $_.L1
    L2 = $_.L2
    L3 = $_.L3
    }
$array += $row
}

#top level directories
$0 = $array | ?{$_.Level -eq 0} |
Select-Object @{n="Address";e={$_.Address;}},@{n="Name";e={$_.L0}}
#2nd level directories
$1 = $array | ?{$_.Level -eq 1} | 
Select-Object @{n="Number";e={$_.Address.split(".")[-1];}},@{n="Name";e={$_.L1}}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it's going to translate to a directory structure very well.  For instance, this row: 01.01,,Mammals,,, would seem to imply a directory namded "Mammals" with a null immediate parent. It almost looks like that needs to be inverted.

Comment: Certainly that's the challenge. The parent of 01.01,,Mammals,,, is indicated by the address element. It's parent is 01, which is to say 01,Species,,,, I'm trying to work out a way to recreate the elements in the path by matching each bit of the address. Perhaps I'm better off trying to make an Excel 'fill down if blank' macro first, and only then use PowerShell to join the cells into a path to create the folders.

Comment: I think I've got something.  Give me a bit to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I think this might do what you want:

```
$root = 'E:\SomeDirName'

Switch -Regex (Get-Content "E:\path\to\file.csv")
{
 '^01,(\w+),,,,$' { $L1,$L2,$L3,$L4 = $null; $L0=$matches[1];mkdir "$root\$L0" }
 '^01\.01,,(\w+),,,$'  { $L1=$matches[1];mkdir "$root\$L0\$L1" }
 '^01\.01\.01,,,(\w+),,$'  { $L2=$matches[1];mkdir "$root\$L0\$L1\$L2" }
 '^01\.01\.01\.01,,,,(\w+),$' { $L3=$matches[1];mkdir "$root\$L0\$L1\$L2\$L3" }
 '^01\.01\.01\.01\.01,,,,,(\w+)$' { $L4=$matches[1];mkdir "$root\$L0\$L1\$L2\$L3\$L4" }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This certainly works to make all the directories with 01 in them. The actual csv has a few hundred folder entries, so I'm trying to come up with a more general solution. I'll think some more about how I can modify this approach to do that, maybe with some kind of loop with $i++ to change the regex, and then post what I come up with.

Comment: If they're all in the right order in the csv, you can change the regexes in the switch to \d+ instead of the '01' literals.

Comment: Okay this works well now, down to 8 levels. Thanks so much. For others who need help on similar, traps to watch for are: need to be sure to sort ascending on address, otherwise folders are missed; matching on (\w+) will miss too many folder names--try ([^:]+) instead. Got file names with en dashes? You're outta luck. (I get Ð instead, and suggestions [here on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970935/using-en-dash-in-an-input-file-to-a-batch-file) to change console font(??) and code page (`chcp 65001`) didn't help.

Comment: For unicode, doing replace on get-content didn't work either, so had to gci & `Rename-Item -Force -NewName {$_ -replace "Ð","–"}` afterwards. Ugly but works.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that kind of problem a programming concept called recursion is often used.

In short a recursive function is a function that call itself.

I successfully tested this code with you CSV input:

```
$csvPath = 'C:\Temp\test.csv'
$folderRoot = 'C:\Temp'

$csv = Import-Csv $csvPath -Delimiter ',' | Sort-Object -Property Address

# Recursive function
function Recurse-Folder( $folderAddress, $basePath )
{
    # Getting the list of current folder subfolders
    $childFolders = $null
    if( $folderAddress -like '' )
    {
        $childFolders = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Address -like '??' }
    }
    else
    {
        $childFolders = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Address -like $( $folderAddress + '.??' ) }
    }

    # For each child folder
    foreach( $childFolder in $childFolders )
    {
        # Get the folder name
        $dotCount = $childFolder.Address.Split('.').Count - 1
        $childFolderName = $childFolder.$('L'+$dotCount)

        if( $childFolderName -ne '')
        {
            $childFolderPath = $basePath + '\' + $childFolderName

            # Creating child folder and calling recursive function for it
            New-Item -Path $childFolderPath -ItemType Directory
            Recurse-Folder $childFolder.Address $childFolderPath
        }
    }

}

Recurse-Folder '' $folderRoot
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. At the moment for me it runs forever making infinite copies in the bottommost dir. I'll sit down in the morning and work through how it works and post a better response. I'm sure I'll learn a lot in any case.