# Batch find and replace en dash with hyphen using Windows batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Multiple files located inside sub folders have similar names and sequential `D.C. _ 18 CA 2616 –00000001.txt`. Would like to find and replace the "en dash" char found right before `0000*` with a hyphen.

e.g From `D.C. _ 18 CA 2616 –00000001.txt` to `D.C. _ 18 CA 2616 -00000001.txt`

Already tried...

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=–"
Set "Replace=-"

For /R %%a in (*–*) Do (
set "File=%%~nxa"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Honestly instead of a script writing, I'd take an existing solution. There's a lot of file renamers around...

Comment: I'd go for PowerShell or something else that supports Unicode characters like the en dash...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very tricky task as the *en dash* character is Unicode code point U+2013. In default Windows command processor, it uses the 437 console code page. The `û` character is character number 150 in code page 437. So it looks like one process is writing a file in code page 1252, while another is reading it using code page 437. - Better explanation about issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971042/8667430)

To fix this, we can use `chcp 1252` at the beginning of the script to change the the 437 console code page to 1252.

Since we are dealing with Unicode characters, if you attempt to paste the `û` into a basic text-file editor, it will change it stright to a *en dash*. To get around this, I'm using the editor [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and changing the encoding in the editor (Encoding, Character sets, Western European, OEM-US) to allow the editor to paste in the `û` character. - More explanation about issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426204/8667430).

**ChangeEnDashToDash.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
chcp 1252>NUL

Rem | Get Each File Name
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "*.txt" /b') do (

    Rem | Get Each File Name
    for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('Echo %%A^| find /i "û"') do (

        Rem | Save Original Name
        Set "OriginalName=%%B"

        Rem | Get New Name
        SET "ModifiedName=!OriginalName:û=-%!"

        Ren "!OriginalName!" "!ModifiedName!"

    )
)

goto :EOF
```

The code bellow will change any `–` to `-` simply by using [syntax-replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). To get the `.txt` files we can use a `for` loop along with `dir "*.txt" /b`. Then by using `Echo %%A^| find /i "û"` it will display only the file names with `–`. From there we can set a few strings and rename them.

If you wish to also search sub-directories change `dir "*.txt" /b` to `dir "*.txt" /b /s`. I have left some `rem` statements to help explain the script process.

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- So on.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried running your command but unfortunately received the following error screenshot. Note that I am using a Mac running Virtual Box/Windows XP. Do you think I need to copy the code while within my Virtual windows box and paste to Notepad ++?

Comment: @gridline81 Did you follow my instructions about using the Western European, OEM-US Encoding? First Paste in the code. Next change the encoding and paste in the `û`. And for your VM, yes, we are dealing with unicode and I would highly suggest you sign into your stackoverflow on your VM (If possible) and copy and paste from that.